# NSURLSessionResponseCancel produces error?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiontask

I used `NSURLConnection`object and called its method `cancel` sometimes.

Now I should replace `NSURLConnection` -> `NSURLSession`. `NSURLSession` operates with tasks which have `cancel` method too.

The problem is `-[NSURLConnection cancel]` just stop the handling of requests but if I use `-[NSURLSessionTask cancel]` it produces "cancelling error". So how to properly distinguish if `cancel` is called manually or if a real error is occurred?

Comment: What is the precise content of this error?  I assume it's an `NSError` object?  If so what is the value of `code`?

Comment: po error gives `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=..., NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=...}` "..." - just links. And there is no info in documentation that this error is sent on manual cancel only

Comment: So I would say compare `error.code` to `-999`.

Comment: Again. What if it was cancelled by iOS system?

Comment: Then you get a different code I expect.

Comment: I don't expect it so I want to find at least a way to handle it manually

Answer (score 0):

I've found 3 solutions:

- subclass task/session class
- create a custom property via method swizzling in task/session class
- the simplest but not very beautiful way - task has string property `taskDescription` and documentation says that developers are free to use it as they want.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the error code to *NSURLErrorCancelled*.  This error code is generated only when **your code** cancels the request.

Comment: again - there is no info in documentation that it is sent by my code

Comment: I wrote many of those docs years ago, so that's probably my fault.  The URL loading system does not, AFAIK, ever cancel requests.  Requests either succeed or fail.  There are only three ways I know of to get that error code: by calling the completion handler block in your didReceiveResponse method with `NSURLSessionResponseCancel`, by calling the `cancel` method on the task, or possibly by calling the authentication completion handler block with `NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge`, and I'm not certain about that last one.  In all three cases, your code did the canceling.